# Ways to express "The reader may wish to..." / "The reader may want to..."

Tags: traduction, anglais, science

> As an application the reader may wish to prove...

(see for instance [here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=a886AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&dq=The%20reader%20may%20wish%20to%20show&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifkuva7rHjAhXVBGMBHT9MDkcQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=The%20reader%20may%20wish%20to%20show&f=false))

> The reader may want to show that for our example...

What are some standard ways (if it is a common practice as in English) to interpret in French the expressions

*the reader may wish to*/*the reader may want to*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En français on trouve beaucoup dans ce contexte une utilisation du verbe « inviter », mais elle ne correspond pas à l'anglais exactement ; voilà un exemple trouvé dans le reverso;

- Readers may wish to refer to the section further  delay is not an option (Section 1) to grasp the need for this plan. (pharmacists.ca)
  *Le lecteur est invité à se reporter à la section  « L'attentisme n'est pas une option » (section 1) pour connaître la raison d'être de ce plan.(pharmacists.ca)*

On trouve à partir du [reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/may+wish+to) que le verbe « souhaiter » est utilisé très souvent, cependant c'est une utilisation au futur et modifiée par l'addition de « peut être »;

Quand il s'agit d'une traduction en français de « the reader may wish to » toutes sortes d'options sont possibles; en voici quelque unes tirées du [reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/the+reader+may+wish+to) ;

- The reader may also wish to refer …
  Le lecteur **pourra** se référer …
- For more details, the interested reader may wish to peruse …
  Pour plus de détails, les lecteurs intéressés **peuvent aller** consulter …
- In addition, readers may wish to consult …
  De plus, les lecteurs **peuvent** consulter …
- Readers may wish to refer to …
  Le lecteur **voudra peut-être** se reporter à …
- For more on this topic, readers may wish to see X.
  X **fournit** plus de renseignements à ce sujet.
- Readers may wish to consult …
  Le lecteur **est invité** à consulter …

À mon avis il n'y a pas de forme qui s'impose par dessus toute autre; il y a d'autres possibilités que celles citées, évidemment.

Récapitulation des formes principales trouvées dans le reverso pour une traduction de « may wish to »

- souhaitera peut-être, voudra peut-être, souhaiteront peut-être, voudront peut-être, souhaitera sans doute, pourrait souhaiter, peut souhaiter, pourraient souhaiter, voudra sans doute, peuvent souhaiter, est invitée à, pourra souhaiter
  

Answer (score 3):

I think the closest is:

> Si le lecteur le souhaite

Answer (score 3):

Il est probable qu'on ne traduise pas ces expresssions de la même façon car elles n'ont aucun lien sémantique. La question posée évoque *partiellement* les expressions, avec pour conséquence des erreurs d'interprétation. Par exemple, dans la première expression mentionnée, il me semble que l'objet de l'action est de prouver quelque chose pour éprouver ou démontrer sa connaissance de la notion avec un cas d'application. J'aurais traduit la première expression comme cela : « Une application serait de prouver... ».

**Remarque :** la première expression est [extraite du livre](https://books.google.fr/books?id=a886AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&dq=The%20reader%20may%20wish%20to%20show&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifkuva7rHjAhXVBGMBHT9MDkcQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=The%20reader%20may%20wish%20to%20show&f=false) « Companion to Concrete Mathematics ».

> In each case a simple substitution leads to evaluating the integral. ***As an application the reader may wish to*** prove the following: let `C` be an arc of the curve `y = ax^{m/n}` where `m` and `n` are relatively prime integers, let `L(C)` be the length of `C`, `A_x(C)` the area of the surface obtained by rotating `C` about the `x-`axis, and `A_y(C)` the same for the `y-`axis. Then `L(C)` is expressible by elementary functions if and only if `2m - 2n|n` or `2m  - 2n|m`; `A_x(C)` if and only if `2m - 2n|m + n` or `m - n|m`;  `A_y(C)` if and only if `m - n|m` or `2m - 2n|m +n`.

On constate qu'il y a un **problème de traduction** en transposant les traductions propo­sées dans le contexte d'origine : la réponse acceptée [élude le problème](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37449/19460), l'autre est [insensée](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37446/19460) « *Si le lecteur (le) souhaite* prouver [l'énoncé suivant]... ».